# The property pipe is not available for type "OperatorFunction<unknown, [unknown, boolean, any]>"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have subscribed to data which I want to pipe. But somehow it does not work. I get this error :

> The property pipe is not available for type "OperatorFunction<unknown,
> [unknown, boolean, any]>"

This is my code:
`auth.service`

```
authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

checkToken() {
    this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(access => {
    if (access) {
        this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(access);
        this.authenticationState.next(true);
    }
});
```

`page.ts` (where I get the error at pipe)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = combineLatest (
    this.authService.authenticationState, 
    from(this.storage.get(USER_ID)))
        .pipe(
            switchMap(
                ([isAuthenticated, id]) => isAuthenticated 
                    ? this.userService.getUserDetails(id) 
                    : of(null)
                )
        ).subscribe(result => {
            if (result) {
                this.information = result;
                console.log(this.information);
            } else {
            }
        },
        error => {}
    );
}
```

Comment: Where is `html` were you have put `pipe`. I would like to see on which variable have you applied it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error suggest that you are importing `combineLatest` from the wrong place, you need to import the `combineLatest` from `rxjs` instead of `rxjs/operators`. You need the "observable creation" version of `combineLatest`, which resides in `rxjs`.

Also you don't need `from` inside `combineLatest`, for the `Storage`, `combineLatest` accepts a Promises as well.

Change your import of `combineLatest` to:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```